# Best way to save DataSet to a CSV file

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I have some SQL queries that I need to write out the results to a CSV file.

I'm currently storing the results in a DataSet.

What is the best way to to save each table (using a user-defined filename) as its own CSV file?

I'm using C#.

Comment: Also take a look at the Stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888181/convert-datatable-to-csv-stream

Answer (score 4):

You can convert a dataset to a CSV file as follows:

Code snippet:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow dr in this.NorthwindDataSet.Customers) 
{
 foreach (object field in dr.ItemArray) 
 {
   str.Append(field.ToString + ",");
 }
 str.Replace(",", vbNewLine, str.Length - 1, 1);
}

try 
{
 My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\\temp\\testcsv.csv", str.ToString, false);
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
 MessageBox.Show("Write Error");
}
```

Hope this helps!
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the DataSet (Tables, Rows, Fields)

C# Example:

```
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataTable dt in tempDataDS.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (object field in item.ItemArray)
                {
                    str.Append(field.ToString() + ",");
                }
                str.Replace(",", Environment.NewLine, str.Length - 1, 1);
            }
        }
        try
        {
            File.AppendAllText("C:\\temp\\tempData.csv", str.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error while writing content to csv file. \nException details: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use http://www.filehelpers.com anytime I need to export to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can export to csv on its own, have a look at

http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-2005/how-can-i-export-data-to-csv-format-in-sql-server-2005/

Edit: This solution isn't very tolerant of characters that need escaping in a csv, took a couple of minutes to write a breaking test. In other words, use with caution.

Comment: will that help him out as well if he's using sql server 2008 R2 as for example..?

Comment: Worked on 2008 (non-R2) but it's dodgy with characters that need escaping in CSVs. Updated the answer to reflect that.