# Spreadsheetgear - get string representation of a range of cells

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I recently started using SpreadsheetGear to parse an Excel file. I needed to go through each row and display the string representation of the first 6 columns. What I did was this:

```cs
    Debug.Print(ssgSheet.Cells(i,0).Text)
    Debug.Print(ssgSheet.Cells(i,1).Text)
    Debug.Print(ssgSheet.Cells(i,2).Text)
    Debug.Print(ssgSheet.Cells(i,3).Text)
    Debug.Print(ssgSheet.Cells(i,4).Text)
    Debug.Print(ssgSheet.Cells(i,5).Text)
```

Where 'i' is the current row of the worksheet. This isn't very pretty, but for now it's not a big deal if I use the 6-liner version for debugging. I also tried this:

```cs
    Debug.Print(ssgSheet.Cells(i, 0, i, 5).Text)
```

but I only get a blank line.

I was just wondering if there is a simple way built into SpreadsheetGear to get a row or range of cells, and just have it returned as some kind of delimited string? I couldn't find an appropriate function to do this on the [SpreadsheetGear API site](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.3.0/SpreadsheetGear~SpreadsheetGear_namespace.html) but maybe I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Range to DataTable**

I don't know of any built-in function in SpreadsheetGear to get a delimited string from a range of cells. However, there is a built-in function to get a DataTable from a range of cells.

```
DataTable dt = ssgSheet.Cells[i, 0, i, 5].GetDataTable(SpreadsheetGear.Data.GetDataFlags.None);
```

(You may want to set the flags differently depending on whether you have column names.)

Once you have a DataTable, you can get a delimited string using code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888181/convert-datatable-to-csv-stream) or from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959722/c-sharp-datatable-to-csv).

**Save Range in CSV format to Stream**

Another option is to save the range in CSV format to a Stream and then get a delimited string from the Stream.

```
using (System.IO.MemoryStream mstream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
  ssgSheet.Cells[i, 0, i, 5].SaveToStream(mstream, SpreadsheetGear.FileFormat.CSV);
  mstream.Position = 0;
  System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(mstream);
  Debug.Print(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void FormatedExport(string destinationFileName, ref DataTable sourceTable, ref FileExportParameters fileExportParameters)
{
    // Create a new workbook and worksheet.
    IWorkbook _workbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook();
    IWorksheet _worksheet = _workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

    // Get the top left cell for the DataTable.
    SpreadsheetGear.IRange _range = _worksheet.Cells["A1"];

    // Copy the DataTable to the worksheet range.
    _range.CopyFromDataTable(sourceTable, SpreadsheetGear.Data.SetDataFlags.None);

    // Auto size all worksheet columns which contain data
    _worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit();

    // Stream the Excel spreadsheet to the client in a format
    // compatible with Excel 97/2000/XP/2003/2007/2010.
    if (fileExportParameters.exportType == ExportType.Excel)
       _workbook.SaveAs(destinationFileName, SpreadsheetGear.FileFormat.Excel8);
    else if (fileExportParameters.exportType == ExportType.FormatedText)
      _workbook.SaveAs(destinationFileName, SpreadsheetGear.FileFormat.CSV);

}
```