# SAS readable files from C# and TSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sas

I have a C# application that reads data from a MS SQL Server database. What I need to do is to create a class that

- recovers data from certain views on the database
- writes the data to files which are in a SAS-readable format

In other words : I need to produce a .SAS7BDAT file from a DataTable inside C# which contains data from a SQL Server database.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Nope, not clear.  I'm not sure what `recovers data from views` means, nor do I know what a `SAS-readable format` is.

Comment: Recovers data from view : has a DataTable object in memory with all the data. One that could be easily used to write the data to a .csv file, for instance. SAS readable format: a data file that can be imported directly into SAS without any intermediate conversion step.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of [writing a csv from a datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14971077/2589202).  How does yours differ?

Comment: In that I have to write a file directly readable from SAS, not a csv.

Comment: Perhaps there are those on SO who immediately know what the specs for a SAS readable format are.  But for those that dont, you could enlighten us.

Comment: The question is intended for people who know SAS, of course. Otherwise, I would have not asked it. I need to produce a  .SAS7BDAT file from a DataTable inside C# which contains data from a SQL Server database. That's it.

Comment: Do you have access to a SAS installation or server of any sort?  SAS is a closed format, and while SAS provides an OLEDB driver for reading SAS files, it doesn't provide a free way to write them.

Comment: @Giuseppe, that is much more clear, perhaps you could edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: I do not have a SAS installation but should provide the output files to someone who does.

Comment: The importance of the SAS installation is in the writing.  You normally would need a SAS installation (either a local copy of base, or a server) to write a SAS7BDAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible without SAS, or a custom library not freely available.

SAS provides OLEDB drivers for this purpose, but they require a SAS installation (of various sorts), as referred to in [this table](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/oledbpr/63701/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p155c49r5ma8hwn15whw1ihsudy3.htm).  You can *read* SAS7BDAT with the free local provider, but not write.

CozyROC sells a [SAS compatible .NET library](http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/sas-data-source) that allows you to write to SAS directly.  That's the only way I'm aware you could do this.  [Alan Churchill](http://www.savian.net/) has done this also on his own (decoded the SAS7BDAT format), but I suspect he sold his work to CozyROC since he now links to them.