# Most efficient way of converting a DataTable to CSV

Tags: c#, performance, csv, datatable

I'm working with DataTable's and I need to convert them to a CSV file format. Most of the tables I am working with have over 50,000 records so I'm trying to minimize the time it takes to convert them.

Here is my current method:

```
    public static string table_to_csv(DataTable table)
    {
        string file = "";

        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            file = string.Concat(file, col.ColumnName, ",");

        file = file.Remove(file.LastIndexOf(','), 1);
        file = string.Concat(file, "\r\n");

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
                file = string.Concat(file, item.ToString(), ",");

            file = file.Remove(file.LastIndexOf(','), 1);
            file = string.Concat(file, "\r\n");
        }

        return file;
    }
```

Is there any way I can improve the efficiency of this method? I'm welcome to any modifications and ideas that you have!

Comment: Since your code is working and you're not facing problems with it, maybe [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is better place for your question than StackOverflow.

Comment: Why are you loading so many rows in the first place? It would be easier to use the database's tools (like SSIS in SQL Server) to export data to CSVs. Or use a DataReader to read data in a firehose mode and write them to a file. Creating the entire string in memory is *not* efficient either - use Write and WriteLine to write them out to a file. Moreover, you can replace repeated concatenations with String.Join, although using `Write` makes it a bit redundant as well

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert DataTable to CSV stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888181/convert-datatable-to-csv-stream)

Comment: I don't think the answers are a good fit for CodeReview, and I don't think this is off-topic here. `trying to minimize the time it takes to convert them` sounds like a problem statement to me, and that might just be on-topic here. a migration would be declined

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use a [System.Text.StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for huge strings - that's pretty fast.
I implemented this one:

```
public static string DataTableToCSV(this DataTable datatable, char seperator)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(datatable.Columns[i]);
        if (i < datatable.Columns.Count - 1)
            sb.Append(seperator);
    }
    sb.AppendLine();
    foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(dr[i].ToString());

            if (i < datatable.Columns.Count - 1)
                sb.Append(seperator);
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This answer meets my requirements, a DataTable containing over 30k records used to take minutes, now takes under 1 second. Thanks.

Comment: how to convert dataset to csv ?

Comment: @AkhilJain if you have multiple Tables within your DataSet - you can't. If you have one Table then `string result = DataTableToCSV(myDataSet.Tables[0], ',');`

Comment: This is a fantastic solution - just wanted to say thanks for helping me out a bunch!

Answer (score 9):

Here's a method I have in my Utility class. Works well for what I'm doing.

```
 public static void GenerateCSV(DataTable dt)
    {  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            int count = 1;
            int totalColumns = dt.Columns.Count;
            foreach (DataColumn dr in dt.Columns)
            {
                sb.Append(dr.ColumnName);

                if (count != totalColumns)
                {
                    sb.Append(",");
                }

                count++;
            }

            sb.AppendLine();

            string value = String.Empty;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < totalColumns; x++)
                {
                    value = dr[x].ToString();

                    if (value.Contains(",") || value.Contains("\""))
                    {
                        value = '"' + value.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + '"';
                    }

                    sb.Append(value);

                    if (x != (totalColumns - 1))
                    {
                        sb.Append(",");
                    }
                }

                sb.AppendLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: Up voted as this solution also checks and escapes the strings when required.

Comment: Very useful answer. Up voted as this solution also considers escapes.

Answer (score 3):

I have used this method which copies object array to an Excel cell range rather than copying row by row and then column by column & it proved to be quite efficient way

```
    public void ExportToExcel(DataTable dataTable, String pathToSave)
    {
        // Create the Excel Application object
        var excelApp = new ApplicationClass();

        // Create a new Excel Workbook
        Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

        int sheetIndex = 0;

        // Copy the DataTable to an object array
        var rawData = new object[dataTable.Rows.Count + 1, dataTable.Columns.Count];

        // Copy the column names to the first row of the object array
        for (var col = 0; col < dataTable.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            rawData[0, col] = dataTable.Columns[col].ColumnName;
        }

        // Copy the values to the object array
        for (var col = 0; col < dataTable.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < dataTable.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                rawData[row + 1, col] = dataTable.Rows[row].ItemArray[col];
            }
        }

        // Calculate the final column letter
        string finalColLetter = string.Empty;
        const string colCharset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        int colCharsetLen = colCharset.Length;

        if (dataTable.Columns.Count > colCharsetLen)
        {
            finalColLetter = colCharset.Substring(
                (dataTable.Columns.Count - 1) / colCharsetLen - 1, 1);
        }

        finalColLetter += colCharset.Substring((dataTable.Columns.Count - 1) % colCharsetLen, 1);

        // Create a new Sheet
        var excelSheet = (Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets.Add(excelWorkbook.Sheets.Item[++sheetIndex], Type.Missing, 1, XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        excelSheet.Name = dataTable.TableName;

        // Fast data export to Excel
        var excelRange = string.Format("A1:{0}{1}", finalColLetter, dataTable.Rows.Count + 1);
        excelSheet.Range[excelRange, Type.Missing].Value2 = rawData;

        // Mark the first row as BOLD and BLUE
        var headerColumnRange = (Range)excelSheet.Rows[1, Type.Missing];
        headerColumnRange.Font.Bold = true;
        headerColumnRange.Font.Color = 0xFF0000;
        headerColumnRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

        // Save and Close the Workbook
        excelWorkbook.SaveAs(pathToSave, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        excelWorkbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        excelWorkbook = null;

        // Release the Application object
        excelApp.Quit();
        excelApp = null;

        // Collect the unreferenced objects
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
```