# unable to write datatable values to csv file in windows app c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, csv

I am trying to insert datatable contents into csv file and the below code doesn't work.

**CODE:**

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Property", typeof(string));
System.Data.DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
newRow["Name"] = str1;
newRow["Property"] = str2;
dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
dt.WriteToCsvFile("../../Data.csv");    

public static void WriteToCsvFile(this DataTable dataTable, string filePath)
    {
        StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var col in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            fileContent.Append(col.ToString() + ",");
        }
        fileContent.Replace(",", System.Environment.NewLine, fileContent.Length - 1, 1);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var column in dr.ItemArray)
            {
                fileContent.Append("\"" + column.ToString() + "\",");
            }
            fileContent.Replace(",", System.Environment.NewLine, fileContent.Length - 1, 1);
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, fileContent.ToString());
    }
```

`Data.csv` file is placed inside a project folder and the values are not getting added.

Really appreciate any suggestions on this.

**Edit1:**

```
dt.CreateCSVFile("../../Data.csv");

public static void CreateCSVFile(this DataTable dt, string strFilePath)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, true);

        int iColCount = dt.Columns.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
        {
            sw.Write(dt.Columns[i]);
            if (i < iColCount - 1)
            {
                sw.Write(",");
            }
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
            {
                if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                {
                    sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                }
                if (i < iColCount - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(",");
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
```

Comment: take a look :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959722/c-sharp-datatable-to-csv

Comment: _"code doesn't work"_ isn't too helpful sadly

Comment: its working on my system. Did you place `WriteToCsvFile` in a static class? `WriteToCsvFile` is an extension method. It should be in a static class

Comment: @AksheyBhat - yes `WriteToCsvFile`  is inside a static class.

Comment: Why `asp.net` tag? Is it web app or win app?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - Windows app

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you can use

```
dt.WriteToCsvFile("../../Data.csv");
```

there should be no this method in DataTable, if you want to convert DataTable to CVS, you can try the below:

```
public static string DataTableToCSV(this DataTable datatable, char seperator)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(datatable.Columns[i]);
        if (i < datatable.Columns.Count - 1)
            sb.Append(seperator);
    }
    sb.AppendLine();
    foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(dr[i].ToString());

            if (i < datatable.Columns.Count - 1)
                sb.Append(seperator);
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

you can find more in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28503521/382576)

after call that method, you can save the string to file as below:

```
var contents = dt.DataTableToCSV(',');
System.IO.File.WriteAllText (@"D:\exportfile.cvs", contents);
```

Comment: How can I write the contents to csv with this method?

Comment: sorry, what's contents? you just need to pass the DataTable object in it should be ok, and the seperator set to a comma

Comment: how can I give the filename path.

Comment: after run this method, you can get a string of cvs, and you just need to save these into a file is ok, please see my other answer

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't write the contents to CSV. I updated my post and that code works fine, but it doesn't align properly.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help   you sorry for not rewriting your code

```
 using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/CSV/export.csv")))
            {


                writer.WriteLine(" OVERVIEW");
                writer.WriteLine("");
                writer.WriteLine("date : " + DateTimeOffset.Parse(DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

                writer.WriteLine("Name");
                writer.WriteLine("Property");

                writer.WriteLine("");
                writer.WriteLine("");





                writer.WriteLine("Name,Property");

                foreach (var item in List)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}",
                                               item.Name,
                                               item.Property


                                               ));
                }
                writer.Flush();
                output.Position = 0;
                // var document=Server.MapPath("~/Content/ExportedFiles/Exported_Users.csv");
            }


        }
```

Comment: I updated my post. I am using streamwriter to write the contents and it works just fine. But the problem is with the alignments, since the values are not placed property to particular column, they get breaked and are misplaced widely. FYI, these actions are performed in windows app.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov could you please tell me why this is not a valid csv

Comment: Your code writes the string "overview" and empty strings - this breaks the [csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov will it be a valid one if we removed  writer.WriteLine(" OVERVIEW");
                writer.WriteLine("");
                writer.WriteLine("date : " + DateTimeOffset.Parse(DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

                writer.WriteLine("Name");
                writer.WriteLine("Property");

                writer.WriteLine("");
                writer.WriteLine(""); this section

Comment: @vicky if your are looking for alignment better go for any library

Answer (score 0):

Here i converted the DataTable to CSV list. you can save it to file.

Code :

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ToCsvList(this DataTable table)
    {
        List<string> returnList = new List<string>();

        string colmn = string.Join(",", table.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Select(c => c.ColumnName));
        returnList.Add(colmn);

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            returnList.Add(string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
        }

        return returnList;
    }
```