# How to convert Data table into such csv format

Tags: c#, .net

[image]

I want to convert my data table into this csv format.Please help me if anyone have idea how to do that

this is what I have tried.

```
  StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            for (int row = 0; row < dataTable.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                data.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                data.Append(dataTable.Rows[row]["Group"]);
                data.Append(Environment.NewLine);

                for (int column = 0; column < dataTable.Columns.Count; column++)
                {
                   

                    if (column == dataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
                        data.Append(dataTable.Rows[row][column].ToString().Replace(",", ";"));
                    else
                        data.Append(dataTable.Rows[row][column].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',');
                }
```

}

Comment: Where is your effort for this task, give us some code we wait all day to help someone like you.

Comment: Is it possible to merge cells in csv?

Comment: I think it is possible by using loop only,but I am not able to create a logic for that.

Comment: @Amanverma what you posted isn't a CSV or even a text file. CSV is a simple **text** format - one row per record, simple fields and an optional header containing the field names *only*. What you posted shows merged cells and borders. You need Excel for this. You can generate an Excel file easily using a library like eg [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus) with a single line `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(someTable)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888181/convert-datatable-to-csv-stream you can use this

Comment: @Junaid that won't produce the merged headers the OP wants. It will produce a proper CSV file though

Comment: A DataTable doesn't have column groups so where would `TN` and `CH` come from?

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos  TN and CH is coming from data table

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have data table column like this:
TN_USERNAME | TN_NAME | TN_USERTYPE | CH_USERNAME | ...

```
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

//add header for csv file in string builder object (column names)
for(int column = 0; column < dataTable.Columns.Count; column++)
{
    data.Append(dataTable.Columns[column].Name);
    if(column != dataTable.Columns.Count - 1) //last column doesn't ends with ;
        data.Append(";")
}

data.AppendLine();

for (int row = 0; row < dataTable.Rows.Count; row++)
{

    for (int column = 0; column < dataTable.Columns.Count; column++)
    {
        if (column == dataTable.Columns.Count - 1)
            data.Append(dataTable.Rows[row][column].ToString());
        else
            data.Append(dataTable.Rows[row][column].ToString()).Append(";");
    }

    data.AppendLine();
}
```

Comment: CSV doesn't have merged cells and borders, or multiple header lines. What the OP posted is a report rendered as a text, with layout, centered text and borders

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that CSV doesn't have merged cells and borders, from his post I thought he want to create csv file from datatable, as you wrote on his post he would need to create excel file.

Comment: That's why posting links to images instead of putting them in the question itself is discouraged. The question is misleading