# Parsing a comma-delimited string that contains string items that contain commas

Tags: string, parsing

The question is a little confusing, so I will explain with an example. I am not using any language in particular.

I have the following string:

> 0,1,"foo","blue,yellow,red",27

I need to create an array of these comma-delimited values, but as you can see, the forth item (index 3) is a string with quotes that also contains commas.

I need to get that string as one value, with the quotes intact like so:

```
[0, 1, "foo", "blue,yellow,red", 27]
```

Splitting on the commas wont help me, as it will also split the string item. How would I go about parsing this comma-delimited string into the list of items.

Comment: You forgot to tag which programming language you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I just modified my question to say that I am not using any particular language. So answers in any language will do as long as they show the theory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [regular expression should split , that are contained outside the double quotes in a CSV file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603096/regular-expression-should-split-that-are-contained-outside-the-double-quotes-i)

Comment: I'd look at using a JSON parser.  Slap `[]` on the string and then parse.  (You sure it's not JSON you're parsing anyway?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what language you are targeting, but the general approach is to read one character at a time, splitting at commas as usual.  But if you encounter a `"` as the first character of a new item, you set a flag (like `in_quotes`).  If that flag is set, you read all characters until the next `"`, at which time you set the flag to false.

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest using `strtok` using comma as the field separator.  However, if the first character in the string is a double quote, you should use `"` as the field separator.

If I assume that what you showed is a `struct`, I wrote the code in C to print the output on separate lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "0,1,\"foo\",\"blue,yellow,red\",27";

    printf ( "Input string: %s\n", str );

    char * substr;
    char * str_itr = str;
    char comma[] = ",";
    char quote[] = "\"";

    substr = strtok ( str_itr, comma );
    if ( substr )
        printf ( "%s\n", substr );

    substr = strtok ( NULL, comma );
    if ( substr )
        printf ( "%s\n", substr );

    substr = strtok ( NULL, quote );
    if ( substr )
        printf ( "%s\n", substr );

    substr = strtok ( NULL, quote );
    substr = strtok ( NULL, quote );
    if ( substr )
        printf ( "%s\n", substr );

    substr = strtok ( NULL, comma );
    if ( substr )
        printf ( "%s\n", substr );

    return ( 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Perl:

```
my $s = '0,1,"foo","blue,yellow,red",27';
my @l = grep {defined $_} split(/("[^"]*")|,/, $s);
print join("-" , @l), "\n";
```

*Output:*

```
0-1--"foo"---"blue,yellow,red"--27
```