# C++ CSV Parsing with Commas Inside of Quotes

Tags: c++, parsing, csv

I'm building a C++ CSV data parser. I'm trying to access the first and fifteenth columns of the file and read them into two arrays using `getline` commands. For example:

```
for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
{
    getline(posts2,postIDs[j],',');
    for(int k=0;k<14;k++)
    {
        getline(posts2,tossout,',');
    }
    getline(posts2,answerIDs[j],',');
    getline(posts2,tossout,'\r');
```

But, in-between the first and fifteenth columns is a column that is in quotes and contains various commas and loose quote marks. For example:

> ...,"abc, defghijk. "Lmnopqrs, "tuv,"" wxyz.",... <

What would the best way to avoid this column be? I can't getline over it because there are quotes and commas inside of it. After running into a quote, should I read the quoted junk character-by-character until I find **",**  in sequence?

Also, I've seen other solutions, but all of them have been exclusive to Windows/Visual Studio. I'm running Mac OSX ver. 10.8.3 with Xcode 3.2.3.

Thanks in advance!
Drew

Comment: Related (near dupe): http://stackoverflow.com/a/1603175/179910

Answer (score 10):

There is no formal standard for CSV format, but let's note at the outset
that the ugly column you have cited:

```
"abc, defghijk. "Lmnopqrs, "tuv,"" wxyz.",
```

does not conform to what are deemed to be the [Basic Rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules_and_examples) of CSV,
because two of those are:-

- 1) Fields with embedded commas must be quoted.
- 2) Each of the embedded double-quote characters must be represented by a pair of double-quote characters.

If the problem column obeys rule 1) then it doesn't obey rule 2). But we can construe it
so as to obey rule 1) - so we can say where it ends - if we balance the double-quotes as, e.g.

```
[abc, defghijk. [Lmnopqrs, ]tuv,[] wxyz.],
```

The balanced outermost quotes enclose the column. The balanced internal quotes 
can just lack any other indication of being internal except that the balancing
makes them internal.

We'd like a rule that will parse this text as one column,
consistently with rule 1), and that will also parse columns that
*do* obey the rule 2) too. The balancing just exhibited suggests this
can be done, because columns that obey both rules will necessarily be
balance-able too.

The suggested rule is:

- A column runs to the first comma that is preceded by 0 double-quotes or
  is preceded by the last of an even number of double-quotes.

If there is any even number of double-quotes up to the comma, then we know
we can balance enclosing quotes and balance the rest in at least one way.

The simpler rule that you are considering:

> After running into a quote, should I read the quoted junk character-by-character until I find ", in sequence?

will fail if it meets with certain columns that *do* obey rule 2), e.g.

> "Super, ""luxurious"", truck",

The simpler rule will terminate the column after `""luxurious""`. But since
this column conforms to rule 2), adjacent double-quotes are "escaped" double-
quotes, with no delimiting significance. On the other hand the suggested
rule still parses the column correctly, terminating it after `truck"`.

Here is a demo program in which the function `get_csv_column` parses columns
by the suggested rule:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>  

using namespace std;

/*
    Assume `in` is positioned at start of column.
    Accumulates chars from `in` as long as `in` is good
    until either:-
        - Have consumed a comma preceded by 0 quotes,or
        - Have consumed a comma immediately preceded by
        the last of an even number of quotes.
*/
std::string get_csv_column(ifstream & in)
{
    std::string col;
    unsigned quotes = 0;
    char prev = 0;
    bool finis = false;
    for (int ch; !finis && (ch = in.get()) != EOF; ) {
        switch(ch) {
        case '"':
            ++quotes;
            break;
        case ',':
            if (quotes == 0 || (prev == '"' && (quotes & 1) == 0)) {
                finis = true;
            }
            break;
        default:;
        }
        col += prev = ch;
    }
    return col;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream in("csv.txt");
    if (!in) {
        cout << "Open error :(" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (std::string col; in; ) {
        col = get_csv_column(in),
        cout << "<[" << col << "]>" << std::endl;
    }
    if (!in && !in.eof()) {
        cout << "Read error :(" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It encloses each column in `<[...]>`, not discounting newlines, and
including the terminal ',' with each column:

The file `csv.txt` is:

```
...,"abc, defghijk. "Lmnopqrs, "tuv,"" wxyz.",...,
",","",
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price,
1997,Ford,E350,"Super, ""luxurious"", truck",
1997,Ford,E350,"Super, ""luxurious"" truck",
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00,
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00,
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""",,5000.00,
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00,
```

The output is:

```
<[...,]>
<["abc, defghijk. "Lmnopqrs, "tuv,"" wxyz.",]>
<[...,]>
<[
",",]>
<["",]>
<[
Year,]>
<[Make,]>
<[Model,]>
<[Description,]>
<[Price,]>
<[
1997,]>
<[Ford,]>
<[E350,]>
<["Super, ""luxurious"", truck",]>
<[
1997,]>
<[Ford,]>
<[E350,]>
<["Super, ""luxurious"" truck",]>
<[
1997,]>
<[Ford,]>
<[E350,]>
<["ac, abs, moon",]>
<[3000.00,]>
<[
1999,]>
<[Chevy,]>
<["Venture ""Extended Edition""",]>
<["",]>
<[4900.00,]>
<[
1999,]>
<[Chevy,]>
<["Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""",]>
<[,]>
<[5000.00,]>
<[
1996,]>
<[Jeep,]>
<[Grand Cherokee,]>
<["MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded",]>
<[4799.00]>
```

Comment: I am using the function get_csv_column() to parse CSV data which with more than 32KB. The stringstream is becoming junk.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most elegant way in c++ for reading a .csv file with commas inside tokens with quotation marks (i.e. quotes):

```
std::string                           header;
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> cSVRows;
std::ifstream                         reader(fileName);
if (reader.is_open()) {
    std::string line, column, id;
    std::getline(reader, line);
    header = line;
    while (std::getline(reader, line)) {
        std::stringstream        ss(line);
        std::vector<std::string> columns;
        bool                     withQ = false;
        std::string              part{""};
        while (std::getline(ss, column, ',')) {
            auto pos = column.find("\"");
            if (pos < column.length()) {
                withQ = !withQ;
                part += column.substr(0, pos);
                column = column.substr(pos + 1, column.length());
            }
            if (!withQ) {
                column += part;
                columns.emplace_back(std::move(column));
                part = "";
            } else {
                part += column + ",";
            }
        }
        cSVRows.emplace_back(columns);
    }
}
```