# Exporting a HTML Table to Excel from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working with ASP.NET MVC and I have an action method that displays few reports in the view in table format.

I have a requirement to export the same table to an Excel document at the click of a button in the View.

How can this be achieved? How would you create your Action method for this?

Answer (score 7):

In your controller action you could add this:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=thefilename.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

Then just send the user to the same view. That should work.

Comment: Works, thanks. Just a note, Excel complains about content being in a different format than the extension.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using component, called Aspose.Cells (http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/).

It's not free, though the most powerful solution I've tried +)

Also, for free solutions, see: [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c)

Answer (score 1):

Get data from database using your data access methods in dot net.

Use a loop to get each record.

Now add each record in a variable one by one like this.

```
Name,Email,Phone,Country
John,john@john.com,+12345,USA
Ali,ali@ali.com,+54321,UAE
Naveed,naveed@naveed.com,+09876,Pakistan
```

*use 'new line' code at the end of each row (For example '\n')*

Now write above data into a file with extension .csv (example data.csv)

Now open that file in EXCEL

:)

Comment: What if the values contain comma?

Comment: @tony_le_montana: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file