# How to read values from a comma separated file?

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I want to read words in a text file of a line separated by commas in c sharp.

For example, I want to read this line:

```
9/10/2011 10:05,995.4,998.8,995.4,997.5,118000
```

and get the values: `9/10/2011 10:05`, `995.4`, `998.8`, `995.4`, `997.5` and `118000`.

Next, I also need to change the format of the date to `MMddYYYY`, and of the time to `HHmmss` (e.g. `100500`).

I am using this code for reading is there anything wrong

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     StreamReader reader1 = File.OpenText(Path1);
     string str = reader1.ReadToEnd();
     reader1.Close();
     reader1.Dispose();
     //     File.Delete(Path1);

     string[] Strarray = str.Split(new char[] { Strings.ChrW(7) });
     int abc = Strarray.Length - 1;
     int xyz = 0;
     bool status = true;

     while (xyz <= abc)
     {
        try
        {
           status = true;
           string[] strarray1 = Strarray[xyz].Split(",".ToCharArray());
           string SecName = strarray1[0];
           int a2 = 0;
           while (status)  //If the selected list is empty or the text file has selected name this will execute
           {
              status = false;
              string SecSym = strarray1[1];
              int DT = int.Parse(strarray1[2]);
              int TM = int.Parse(strarray1[3]);
              float O = float.Parse(strarray1[2]);
              float H = float.Parse(strarray1[3]);
              float L = float.Parse(strarray1[4]);
              float C = float.Parse(strarray1[5]);
              double OI = double.Parse(Convert.ToString(0));
              float V = float.Parse(strarray1[6]);

              //   string a = string.Concat(SecName, ",",SecSym,",", DT, ",", TM, ",", O, ",", H, ",", L);
              //writer.WriteLine(a);
           }
        }
        catch
        { }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? PLease show what you have tried so far, some code..

Comment: i edited my code pls check it

Comment: This is a solved problem. Check for libraries that parse csv files e.g. FileHelpers / KbCsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1st part of your task use `Split` method with `,` as separator. To convert string datetime from one format to another you need to convert that string to datetime(`DateTime.Parse`, `DateTime.ParseExact`) and then convert to final format using `DateTime.ToString` method.

Comment: @Arshiya, What's the problem? `var result = input.Split(',');`

Comment: i want to use string arrays            For Example  string Sec = strarray1[1];
                            int DT = int.Parse(strarray1[2]);
                            int TM = int.Parse(strarray1[3]);
                            float O = float.Parse(strarray1[2]);
                            float H = float.Parse(strarray1[3]);
                            float L = float.Parse(strarray1[4]);
                            float C = float.Parse(strarray1[5]);
                            double OI = double.Parse(Convert.ToString(0));
                 float V = float.Parse(strarray1[6]);

Comment: @Arshiya - `Split` returns an array of strings.

Answer (score 16):

.Net comes with a ready CSV parser you can use to get your data. It's a part of VB.net, but you can easily use it in C# by adding a reference to the assembly `Microsoft.VisualBasic` (it's OK, honesly), and a using statement: `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;`.

The code should be simple to understand:

```
List<String[]> fileContent = new List<string[]>();

using(FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(@"data.csv")) // mind the encoding - UTF8
using(TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(reader))
{
    parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true; // if you want
    parser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true; 
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        string[] line = parser.ReadFields();
        fileContent.Add(line);
    }
}
```

CSV is fairly simple, but it may contain quoted values with commas and newlines, so using `Split` isn't the best option.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Kobi. I do have to say that the CSV parser that comes with Visual Basic is far more reliable then CsvHelper or FileHelpers Libraries, and parses the document where all other libraries fail.

Answer (score 5):

Use the String.Split method to get an array of strings:

```
string[] ar = line.Split(',')
```

Answer (score 4):

This should get you started.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Sample
{
    public static void Main() {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("yourfile.txt")) {
            string line = null;
            while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine())) {
                string[] values = line.Split(',');
                DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(values[0];
                float[] numbers = new float[values.Length - 1];
                for (int i = 1; i < values.Length - 1; i++)
                    numbers[i - 1] = float.Parse(values[i]);

                // do stuff with date and numbers
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also posted a simple [CsvReader class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file/769713#769713) which may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick and simple solution, you can stream through the file and parse each line using [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) like this:

```
using (var sr = File.OpenText("myfile.csv"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var fields = line.Split(',');
        var date = DateTime.Parse(fields[0].Trim());
        var value1 = fields[0].Trim();
    }
}
```

However, this appraoch if fairly error prone, for a more robust solution check out the [CsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) project, it's excellent for parsing CSV files like this. It will handle field values with commas, trimming spaces before and after fields, and much more.

If you need to parse a date string from a format not recognised by DateTime.Parse, try using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

rows contain your output

```
   StreamReader sStreamReader = new StreamReader("File Path");
    string AllData = sStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
    string[] rows = AllData.Split(",".ToCharArray());
```