# How to write a value which contain comma to a CSV file in c#?

Tags: c#, export-to-csv

I am using a data table for storing data.

I am exporting the data from data table to CSV file.

Sometimes there may be values containing comma(`,`) so the values are not exported correctly.

### For Example

Consider the value is `"9,11,32"`.  I have to export as such.

But when I do the first column conatins `9` then in next column `11`.

I want to display `9,11,32` in the same column in the CSV file. How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: What does "**not exported correctly." mean? Normally you put the data in quotes but it depends on what is _reading_ the file, not on what is writing it. I always suggest you use tab delimited instead then you don't have to worry about commas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 32):

Simply put your data inside the backslash like this: "\"" + yourdata + "\"". Take a look on the example below:

```
StringWriter csv = new StringWriter();
// Generate header of the CSV file
csv.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", "Header 1", "Header 2"));
// Generate content of the CSV file
foreach (var item in YourListData)
{
    csv.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", item.Data1, "\"" + item.Data2 + "\""));
}

return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv.ToString()), "application/csv", string.Format("{0}{1}", "YourFileName", ".csv"));
```

In the example: Your data2 may contains comma ","

Comment: But if My data is like abc,def" then it does not works as you explain. it give one column with abc,def" and second column with value def"". I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: You have to replace one " with two "" in your data.

Answer (score 19):

1. Fields with `embedded commas` must be delimited with double-quote characters.

   **fields:**

   1. `abc, xyz`
   2. `pqr`

**csv version:**

```
"abc, xyz" , pqr
```

2. Fields that contain `double quote` characters must be surounded by double-quotes, and the embedded double-quotes must each be represented by a pair of consecutive double quotes.

   **field:**

   ```
   Welcome to "My World"
   ```

   **csv version:**

   ```
   "Welcome to ""My World"""
   ```

Answer (score 7):

If you have a comma in the data you need to put in a csv the https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180 says to use quotations as:

```
"123,56","A dog, cat and a frog"
```

Answer (score 3):

Put Value in double quotes.

```
string ValueToEscape = "a,b";

"\"" + ValueToEscape + "\""
```

CSV Output = a,b

Answer (score 3):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();          
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            if (col.ColumnName.Contains(","))
            {
                sb.Append(String.Format("\"{0}\",", col.ColumnName));
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(String.Format("{0},", col.ColumnName));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Write Comma separated value between double quote without space to create csv with single column for comaa separated values.

Ex. I have two columns **Code** & **Description** With Values **Code01** & **Val1,Val2,Val3**. To create csv with given data write below line in notepad and save it with csv extension.

```
Code,Description
Code01,"Val1,Val2,Val3"
```