# How to write comma to .csv files C#

Tags: c#, csv

I have the following query -

```
string query = "Insert into table(userId,companyID) values(" + userId + "," + SplitedLine[1] + ")";
writer.WriteLine(query);
```

When I am printing running this code then it is not printing the entire query in one column, rather it is breaking the query wherever there is a comma.

I tried this

[How to write a value which contain comma to a CSV file in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090759/how-to-write-a-value-which-contain-comma-to-a-csv-file-in-c)

```
string query = "Insert into table(userId" +"\",\""+"companyID) values (" + userId + "\",\"" + SplitedLine[1] + ")";
writer.WriteLine(query);
```

But this is printing my insert commands in wrong format.
Please help.

Comment: `string.Join`?..

Comment: Simple answer, I don't think that you can. By definition a comma indicates a new column. You will have to convert the comma into another form, say as html character `&#44` or `\u002C` for unicode. Consider converting the text into something else first.

Comment: Why don't you use *binding variables* instead of *hardcoding* in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tested this out, your simplest approach is to ensure that your query string is double quoted.

```
var query = $"\"Insert into table(userId,companyID values ({userId}, {SplitedLine[1]})\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the title of your question is ambiguous. You wanted to soround the values by quotation marks (`"`). But you made a mistake by escaping the `"` in the table part, it seams escaped `"` and not escaped was misked up.

Try to go with

```
string query = $"Insert into table(\"{userId}\",\"{companyID}\") values(\"{ userId}\",\"{SplitedLine[1]}\")";
```