# How to include "," in a string in a CSV file?

Tags: csv

Pretend you have a string like this:

```
example_string = "
  "Hi, My name is "Fohsap", and I'm dumb"
  "Hi, Fohsap," she interrupted.
"
```

And you're trying to get it into a CSV file like this:

```
"example_recipient","example_string","example_recipient2","example_string2",..."example_recipientN","example_stringN"
```

Comment: Why not enter it in excel (or your preferred equivalent) then save as CSV and see what comes out?

Comment: @John3136 Cool name.  Excel less accessible.  If you didn't, hook me up with another down vote.  Thanks. :)

Comment: I didn't down vote cos at least I can tell what the question you were asking is. Just a comment "see how the big boys do it", but that isn't a real answer.

Comment: @John3136 Good point, though.  Good comment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma should not be a problem (since you will use double quotes around each value), but you need to escape the double quotes.  Here are some guidelines on this: [CSV reader](http://www.csvreader.com/csv_format.php), but it actually depends on what you are using to read the file. You also need to be concerned about your newlines (for Excel as long as you are using quotes it's not a problem, for Unix you need to do the normal Unix escape things like \n)

Comment: Not too concerned about the returns because they seem to work with what I read in.  If they didn't work, I could do a bulk replace operation.  Care to elaborate, though?

Comment: It really depends on what technology you are using to consume the file. The link I provided is pretty complete.

Comment: Direct quote from the guidelines site you mentioned: "In an Excel escaped CSV file, in fields containing a double quote, the double quote must be escaped by replacing the single double quote with two double quotes."

Answer (score 1):

This will vary by [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) implementation used, but one common way is to *quote* fields that include the separator (`,`) character. Note that the *quote* (`"`) character is double-escaped if needed. (See [CSV: Basic Rules and Examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules_and_examples).)

Thus, imagine 3 fields, `a`, `b,c` and `"hello,world"` which might be written as:

```
a,"b,c","""hello,world"""
```

Reasoning for individual fields:

```
a                 <- no escape/quote needed
"b,c"             <- quoted so [,] is not treated as separator
"""hello,world""" <- quoted for [,] and the ["]s are double-escaped
```

I would recommend **not** writing your own CSV (or worse yet, manual string building!) but rather, use an existing library. It will already have the bugs and edge-cases worked out such as what to do with embedded newlines.

Happy coding!

Comment: Manual entry can't always be avoided, so I think it's best to learn the corner cases.  You bring up a good point, though.  When possible, I will use a program to generate the CSV files.  So, thanks for the example.  Basically, you're saying that sometimes a double quote is used to escape a double quote, right?

Comment: Also, your link was a great read.  It gave me some info about different kinds of CSV files.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 It's not about manual entry -- it's about how the data is taken and transformed in the the CSV file. Glad the links were useful :)