# How to split CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, split

```
"0.0.0.0,""0.255.255.255"",""ZZ"""                
"1.0.0.0,""1.0.0.255"",""AU"""
"1.0.1.0,""1.0.3.255"",""CN"""
"1.0.4.0,""1.0.7.255"",""AU"""
"1.0.8.0,""1.0.15.255"",""CN"""
"1.0.16.0,""1.0.31.255"",""JP"""
"1.0.32.0,""1.0.63.255"",""CN"""
"1.0.64.0,""1.0.127.255"",""JP"""
"1.0.128.0,""1.0.255.255"",""TH"""
"1.1.0.0,""1.1.0.255"",""CN"""
"1.1.1.0,""1.1.1.255"",""AU"""
"1.1.2.0,""1.1.63.255"",""CN"""
"1.1.64.0,""1.1.127.255"",""JP"""
"1.1.128.0,""1.1.255.255"",""TH"""
```

İN EXCEL

```
0.0.0.0,"0.255.255.255","ZZ"
1.0.0.0,"1.0.0.255","AU"
1.0.1.0,"1.0.3.255","CN"
1.0.4.0,"1.0.7.255","AU"
1.0.8.0,"1.0.15.255","CN"
1.0.16.0,"1.0.31.255","JP"
1.0.32.0,"1.0.63.255","CN"
1.0.64.0,"1.0.127.255","JP"
1.0.128.0,"1.0.255.255","TH"
1.1.0.0,"1.1.0.255","CN"
1.1.1.0,"1.1.1.255","AU"
1.1.2.0,"1.1.63.255","CN"
1.1.64.0,"1.1.127.255","JP"
1.1.128.0,"1.1.255.255","TH"
1.2.0.0,"1.2.2.255","CN"
1.2.3.0,"1.2.3.255","AU"
1.2.4.0,"1.2.127.255","CN"
1.2.128.0,"1.2.255.255","TH"
1.3.0.0,"1.3.255.255","CN"
1.4.0.0,"1.4.0.255","AU"
1.4.1.0,"1.4.127.255","CN"
1.4.128.0,"1.4.255.255","TH"
```

How can split this CSV file.

For example `0.0.0.0   0.255.255.255  ZZ` for first row and how can add datagridview with 3columns

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly split a CSV using C# split() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207269/how-to-properly-split-a-csv-using-c-sharp-split-function)

Comment: btw it is csv not cvs

Comment: By using a dedicated CSV reader, such as [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/), rather than going through the pain of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This is not even valid CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the following way..

```
using System.IO;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\test.csv"))
    {
        List<string> listA = new List<string>();
        List<string> listB = new List<string>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(','); // or whatever yur get by reading that file

            listA.Add(values[0]);
            listB.Add(values[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain your answer a little bit to make this a good answer

Comment: You may chop a record in the middle when a string value has a \r\n in it.

Answer (score 0):

A `CSV` file is either a `Tab delimited` or a `Comma delimited` file. That said; you have to read the file line by line and then separate the values available in a line based on the `delimiter` character. The first line usually appears in a `CSV` file is usually the headers which you can use in order to produce a `KeyValue` pair to make your collection more efficient. For example:

```
 Dictionary<int, Dictionary<String, String>> values = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<String,String>>();
 using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\MyCSV.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
     using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream)){
          //You can skip this line if there is no header
          // Then instead of Dictionary<String,String> you use List<String>
          var headers = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(',');
          String line = null;
          int lineNumber = 1;
          while(!streamReader.EndOfStream){
               line = streamReader.ReadLine().split(',');
               if(line.Length == headers.Length){
                   var temp = new Dictionary<String, String>();
                   for(int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++){
                      // You can remove '"' character by line[i].Replace("\"", "") or through using the Substring method
                      temp.Add(headers[i], line[i]);
                   }
                   values.Add(lineNumber, temp);
               }
               lineNumber++;
          }              
     }
```

In case the data structure of your `CSV` is constant and it will not change in the future, you can develop a strongly typed data model and get rid of the `Dictionary` type. This approach will be more elegant and more efficient.

Comment: CSV by definition is comma separated values. The similar structure text files that use TAB as delimiter are *not* CSV.

Comment: @PepitoSh: In data mining projects, sometimes a comma delimited CSV is troublesome, so we go for a Tab Delimited one. That is why I mentioned it.

Comment: You should not split the line you read by commas. You may split a string value that has comma in it. Also, you may read a partial record as \r\n may be part of a string value. Parsing CSV is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @PepitoSh: `You may split a string value that has comma in it`, Why? it is the line that is delimited by ',' not the individual records!

Comment: No. In CSV columns are delimited with comma. See Specification: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values And I concur, tabs may be used as delimiters. :)

Comment: @PepitoSh: Exactly, if you mean that separation by a comma may introduce problems, then yes you are very right! My answer is limited to what the OP asked. In that case we have two options, either by convention we wrap each value/column inside a tag or we do not use a comma within values.

Comment: Or we do not call it CSV. :-D

Comment: @PepitoSh: Haha, the same concept that has been adapted in JSON files also applies here. You do not expect me to develop a high-end program and post it as an answer, do you ? :D

Comment: Sure I don't. Particularly that the OP is asking for a DataGridView implementation as well. With 3 columns. For now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your CSV lines are surrounded by quotes. Is it copy/paste mistake? If not, you will need to sanitize the file to a valid CSV file.

You can try [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source library to load the CSV file to datatable, then you can assign it to your DataGridView source.

I'll show you both approach, how to handle

**Valid CSV:** (test.csv)

```
0.0.0.0,"0.255.255.255","ZZ"
1.0.0.0,"1.0.0.255","AU"
1.0.1.0,"1.0.3.255","CN"
1.0.4.0,"1.0.7.255","AU"
1.0.8.0,"1.0.15.255","CN"
1.0.16.0,"1.0.31.255","JP"
1.0.32.0,"1.0.63.255","CN"
1.0.64.0,"1.0.127.255","JP"
1.0.128.0,"1.0.255.255","TH"
1.1.0.0,"1.1.0.255","CN"
1.1.1.0,"1.1.1.255","AU"
1.1.2.0,"1.1.63.255","CN"
1.1.64.0,"1.1.127.255","JP"
1.1.128.0,"1.1.255.255","TH"
```

**Read CSV:**

```
using (var p = new ChoCSVReader("test.csv"))
{
    var dt = p.AsDataTable();
    //Assign dt to DataGridView
}
```

Next approach

**Invalid CSV:** (test.csv)

```
"0.0.0.0,""0.255.255.255"",""ZZ"""
"1.0.0.0,""1.0.0.255"",""AU"""
"1.0.1.0,""1.0.3.255"",""CN"""
"1.0.4.0,""1.0.7.255"",""AU"""
"1.0.8.0,""1.0.15.255"",""CN"""
"1.0.16.0,""1.0.31.255"",""JP"""
"1.0.32.0,""1.0.63.255"",""CN"""
"1.0.64.0,""1.0.127.255"",""JP"""
"1.0.128.0,""1.0.255.255"",""TH"""
"1.1.0.0,""1.1.0.255"",""CN"""
"1.1.1.0,""1.1.1.255"",""AU"""
"1.1.2.0,""1.1.63.255"",""CN"""
"1.1.64.0,""1.1.127.255"",""JP"""
"1.1.128.0,""1.1.255.255"",""TH"""
```

**Read CSV:**

```
using (var p = new ChoCSVReader("Sample6.csv"))
{
    p.SanitizeLine += (o, e) =>
    {
        string line = e.Line as string;
        if (line != null)
        {
            line = line.Substring(1, line.Length - 2);
            line = line.Replace(@"""""", @"""");
        }

        e.Line - line;
    };

    var dt = p.AsDataTable();
    //Assign dt to DataGridView
}
```

Hope it helps.