# csv parsing issue when data include comma

Tags: apex-code

I am retrieving data from DB and make each field merged with Comma between them to generate CSV.

But the problem is one the field is Company Name and the data includes comma which leads to malformed CSV file.

```
Example: Name, Telephone, Email

AAA, 12345, aaa@mail.com
BBB Co,.Ltd, 43466, bbb@gmail.com
```

For the record BBB the generated CSV becomes problem as it includes , in the data.

How should I make the correct CSV for such records of including , ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the developers handle this situation by using different characters instead of "comma". But i would suggest you to look into an old post here
[Dealing with commas in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

Is your question related to Salesforce APEX?

When the CSV was generated there ought to be an option to enclose the fields in Double quotes so that commas can appear inside the field content.  For example  "Company, Name","1234","etc."

The CSV generator will also "escape" any double quotes inside a field like this "Some field with \"double\" quotes","123","etc"

This all means you need a CSV parser that can handle these situations.
If your question is related to Salesforce APEX then it is quite difficult to build such a CSV parser because of the limitations Salesforce imposes on the number of statements that can run in any given action.

Comment: yes, I am talking about Salesforce apex. I am trying to make the CSV format out of DB's record by appending , between each field by myself. Thus I am facing problem for some records which are included , in their data.