# Splitting data in CSV file

Tags: java, csv

Below is the data format in my CSV file

userid,group,username,status

In my Java code I delimited the data by using `,` as delimiter

Eg:

normal scennario in which my code works fine:

```
1001,admin,ram,active
```

in this scenario(user with firstname,lastname) when i take the status of the 1002 user it is coming as KUMAR since it is taking 4th column as status

```
1002,User,ravi,kumar,active
```

Kindly help me on how to change the code logic so that it works fine for both the scenenarios

Comment: Check out the "Related" questions over to the right. There is one with over 100 upvotes which is on this same subject.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenCSV library](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net).

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName),';');
List<String[]> rows = csvReader.readAll();
```

then you can test the first column : if rows.get(0)[0] == 1002 ....