# How to read xlsx from String in java using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, export-to-csv, xlsx

There are plenty of examples of how to convert xlsx to csv. I would appreciate if someone show just a snippet of code of how to convert xlsx which is already in String and return csv in String[].

Answer (score 0):

[Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html#to-csv) already have **example** to convert `csv` format. [ToCSV.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/ToCSV.java) is good example. There is no build-in function. Otherwise, you have to write your own code. [Convert .xls to csv file using apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781826/convert-xls-to-csv-file-using-apache-poi)

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. My question is not how to convert xlsx to csv. I have xlsx already in String in memory. My question is how to open workbook and read xlsx from the String.