# Handling commas inside the content for a CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, delimiter

I have a CSV field with delimiter , . but in the following code i placed the content itself has multiple commas and quotes within it , how should I change this data so that its easy to import to sql
the content in one field is as follows

```
"head META content="MSHTML 6.00.6000.21342" name=GENERATOR /head bodyP class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 10pt" SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; LINE-HEIGHT: 115%; FONT-FAMILY: 'Tahoma','sans-serif'"SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; LINE-HEIGHT: 115%; FONT-FAMILY: 'Tahoma','sans-serif'; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-fareast-theme-font: minor-latin; mso-ansi-language: EN-US; mso-fareast-language: EN-US; mso-bidi-language: AR-SA">atVantage™ "
```

Comment: Try reading this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file

Comment: this is what i did reading that but was in vain . "<head><META content=""MSHTML 6.00.6000.21342"" name=GENERATOR></head><body><P class=MsoNormal style=""MARGIN: 0in 0in 10pt""><SPAN style=""FONT-SIZE: 10pt; LINE-HEIGHT: 115%; FONT-FAMILY: 'Tahoma','tans-serif. the error came in at a comma next to tahoma

Comment: ?? Thats not a CSV. What individual fields are you hoping to get out of that string?

Comment: You can change the delimiter to pipe or tab or something never used in the data.