# How to remove POS tags and and other characters from a CSV line in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I remove commas, brackets, parentheses and POS tags from a string read from a CSV file?

Example Input String:

```
'[("it", "P"), ("was", "VP"), ("sleeping", "N")]' , ' [("is", "P"), ("it", "VP"), ("correct", "N")] '
```

Example output:

> it was sleeping , is it correct

Comment: What do you mean by csv-format?

Comment: the data is formatted as I posted

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: not only the problem with coma I need to remove the POS tag how to do that?

Comment: I've edited your question to make it more clear, and removed the code formatting from the example output. Also, I removed the follow-up question. SO questions should only address one topic. If you need further help after getting your string formatted, you should ask a new question (after searching to see if it already exists, of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can control the csv formatting with arguments to csv.reader:

```
import csv

data = csv.reader(<file>, quotechar='\'', skipinitialspace=True)
print([" ".join([e[0] for e in eval(field.strip())]) for row in data for field in row])
```

Output:

```
['it was sleeping', 'is it correct']
```