# Sybase to SELECT INTO CSV with fields containing comma

Tags: java, sql, sybase

In MySql we can programmically export table into CSV via the following command:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' FROM MyTable;
```

However is there a Sybase ASE equivalent to export table programmically into CSV? Also, that data may contain commas as well. Is there a command in Sybase to handle commas in data?

If there isn't I think I can only use `ResultSet` and loop and append. And in `ResultSet` I can explicitly handle the commas myself.

In order for Sybase ASE to export data to CSV, SQLAnywhere is required. I think I will just use `ResultSet`. Since the rows for the table is less than 100 at anytime, I think it won't take a performance blow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file

Comment: Ok thanks Jozef Chocholacek I will look at that thread.