# Reading a CSV in R that contains commas in an element

Tags: r

I'm reading in a CSV in R using `read.csv`.

It's a list of countries and their respective identifiers, such as:

```
Name, ID
Andorra, AD
Russia, RU
"VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH", VG
```

Reading it in like this will separate on the comma enclosed by the quotation marks, which means that for the 3rd element it will show VIRGIN ISLANDS as the country name, and then `BRITISH` as the `ID`.

How do I force it to read in everything encapsulated by the quotation marks as a single element?

Thanks

Comment: Check out this link, could help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file

Comment: Thanks - the solution below solves the problem for me for reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
con <- textConnection('Name, ID\nAndorra, AD\nRussia, RU\n"VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH", VG')
csv <- read.csv(con, quote='"')
csv
```

Actually, this is the default value for the `quote`, hence I am not sure why you had problem in the first way.

Comment: The answer, as always, is because I'm an idiot. I had quote="", rather than quote='"'. (i.e. two doubles, not single double single).

Thanks so much.

Comment: Or you can use `"\""`

Comment: The ultimate solution is to be less of an idiot, really :) quote="" was just a dumb thing to do, had I spent even a minute's brain power I'm sure I would have realised why it was dumb.