# reading from .csv file in c++

Tags: c++, csv

I am writing a program that needs to load a small database from a .csv file.  Normally I would just look for the ',' character with getline(file, data, ',') to find each new cell but I can't do that here.  Some of the cells have strings with commas in them and when I do this it splits some of the cells.  So my question is how can I read each cell without looking for the commas?  Is there a simple way I don't know about to grab just the next cell instead of looking for the comma character?

Comment: If you want a robust solution, probably best to use a third-party library.

Comment: So what is "the next cell"? How do you recognize it? Are there spaces, have all the cells the same width?

Comment: csv is by default a spreadsheet that opens in excel.  C++ sees it as a text file with cells separated by commas and rows separated by newlines.  I'm not sure how excel distinguishes between the new cell character and a regular comma.

Comment: @Jack - Excel can enclose cell values in quotes. The quoted strings can contains commas (that are not separators). See this question [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file?rq=1)