# Compare values with a static and global table in C++

Tags: c++, statistics, ais

I am working on statistical analyses in my field, and using c++. I am implementing several tests, and some of them need to compare the calculated value with a table, say a distribution table for example, like [this one.](http://www.socr.ucla.edu/applets.dir/f_table.html)

I want my different functions in my different classes to be able to access a specific value, to evaluate the significance of my result, for example something like this:

```
float F = fisherTest(serie1, serie2);
auto tableValue = findValue(serie1.size(), serie2.size());

if(tableValue < F) {
        cout << "Not significant";
        return -1;
    }
```

This is just an example, as this test actually makes no sense. But I just want to be able to read values from a predefined table.

Do you have an idea of how I can achieve this? Can I store this in a "resource file"?

I hope my question is clear! Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the equation used to create the table?

Comment: @tobi303 indeed you are correct. I added my question.

Comment: @UKMonkey I thought of that but I believe these are complex statistical tables, so several equations is my guess

Comment: you could pull in [the table as a .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218040/how-to-read-a-csv-file-data-into-an-array) text file perhaps and build an array. that would be easy enough.

Comment: The class you're looking for is std::fstream.

Comment: Check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/fisher_f_distribution

Answer (score 0):

You can have some data files and pass a configuration during startup (e.g. commandline) to the application so it can find the files and read them. The data structure can then be fed to the test.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the predefined data from several sources:

1. Hard coded tables in your program.
2. One or more functions that can compute the data on demand.
3. Files on your local disk.
4. Data stored in a database server.

You and your team need to decide which makes the most sense for your application.