# Python write to csv ignore commas

Tags: python, csv

I am writing to a csv and it works good, except some of the rows have commas in there names and when I write to the csv those commas throw the fields off...how do I write to a csv and ignore the commas in the rows

```
header = "Id, FACID, County, \n"
row = "{},{},{}\n".format(label2,facidcsv,County)
with open('example.csv', 'a') as wildcsv:
    if z==0:
        wildcsv.write(header)
        wildcsv.write(row)
    else:
         wildcsv.write(row)
```

Comment: You should enclose those in double quotes like it's presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/769675/6313992 - `row = "\"{},{},{}\"".format(label2,facidcsv,County)`

Comment: What about [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strip any comma from each field that you write to the row, eg:

```
label2 = ''.join(label2.split(','))
facidcsv = ''.join(facidcsv.split(','))
County = ''.join(County.split(','))
row = "{},{},{}\n".format(label2,facidcsv,County)
```

---

Generalized to format a row with any number of fields:

```
def format_row(*fields):
    row = ''
    for field in fields:
        if row:
            row = row + ', ' + ''.join(field.split(','))
        else:
            row = ''.join(field.split(','))
    return row

label2 = 'label2, label2'
facidcsv = 'facidcsv'
county = 'county, county'
print(format_row(label2, facidcsv, county))
wildcsv.write(format_row(label2, facidcsv, county))
```

**Output**

```
label2 label2, facidcsv, county county
```

---

As @TomaszPlaskota and @quapka allude to in the comments, Python's `csv` `writers` and `readers` by default write/read csv fields that contain a delimiter with a surrounding `'"'`. Most applications that work with csv files follow the same format. So the following is the preferred approach if you want to keep the commas in the output fields:

```
import csv

label2 = 'label2, label2'
facidcsv = 'facidccv'
county = 'county, county'
with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow((label2, facidcsv, county))
```

**out.csv**

```
"label2, label2",facidccv,"county, county"
```

Comment: hmm okay this could work--I have about 20 something fields to write tho (didnt include that in the question) any way to do a mass comma remove on all columns and rows?