# How to convert a dictionary into a suitable format to save to file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I am new to python - however have encountered a problem

I have a file saved which looks like:

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
```

I can convert this to a dictionary by using this code:

```
file = open("dict.txt",'r')
dictionary = {}

    for line in file:
        x = line.split(",")
        key = x[0]
        value = x[1]
        value = value [:-1]
        dictionary[key] = value
```

There is code that allows the user to element (so dictionary now consists of a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4)

However, I need to get the dictionary in the form mentioned above

So

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,4
```

Is this possible?

Also if some explanations could go with the answer I'd appreciate it

Comment: Use the `csvWriter` module.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution without importing modules

Comment: Then use a simple `for` loop that iterates over the dictionary, and writes the key and value separated by comma.

Comment: Can I ask what is wrong with importing modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you've specified, you can loop through a dictionary's key/value pairs using the `items()` function, and write each pair to the file:

```
data_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

with open('data.txt', 'w') as file:
    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        file.write(str(key) + ',' + str(value) + '\n')
```

Of course, change `data_dict` to your dictionary, etc - this is just an example.

There are a couple of edge cases where this will not work, such as if either the key or the value contain commas. If you're looking to properly store comma-separated data, you may want to have a look at the [builtin csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: Your example works as long as the keys do not have commas.

Comment: Nope, that's not how CSV works. When there is a comma in a CSV field, it is escaped (`\,`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file

Comment: It' ok, I'm just warning the OP about its limitations.

Comment: @DYZ i'll edit a description of the limitations into the post :)