# Specifying delimiters in CSV Data Configs

Tags: csv, jmeter, config, delimiter

One of the API parameters can hold values like “2343242,999324” .
How can I specify this in Data CSV config  because currently If I do specify the request just takes 2343242 and not the comma and 999324 part. I have made Allow quoted data to True as well. Anyone pls ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following steps to achieve it:

```
1) Set Allow quoted data to True
2) Change Delimiter(use '\t' for tab) from , to | in CSV DataSetConfig.
3) Separate datadriven values in csv file by | rather than ,
```

Eg: anyNumericValue|"2343242,999324"|anyTextValue

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in CsV Datadet any delimiter you want , for example ; instead of , :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config