# Can a tsv file contain tabs?

Tags: csv

I have to store data containing tabulations in a file. I would like to use [.TSV](https://www.humblix.com/Ilkz2z/what-does-the-acronym-or-file-extension-tsv-stand-for/) files (Tab-Separated File).

Here is an example of data (I manually escaped tabs and carriage return for the example):

```
                       Computation                   Display
0  for (int i=0;i<10;i++)\n\tx*=3;  printf ("<b>éàè'"</b>");
1                 float pi=3.1415;     printf("%d %f",x,xf);
```

Is there a proper way to escape tabs? Should I use \t, should I use quotes or double quotes?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, please try to improve it.

Comment: @Mark What is unclear with my question ? Tabs are delimiters, so what if there is tabs in the data ?

Comment: TSVs and CSVs can have whatever you want in them. There are no laws. The more unusual/extreme the contents, the less compatible the file will be. They are your files, use them how you wish - just ensure that whatever you create is readable by whatever tools you wish to use.

Comment: I think the phrasing of question is little ambiguous, in particular, "data containing tabulations". This could refer either to TAB characters in the data, or to "tabular data" generally, such a table of numbers. However, the title seems relatively clear about intending TAB characters in the data. Perhaps a data snippet containing tab characters would clear things up.

Comment: FWIW: Seems clear to me with the new edits. Question is if TAB characters (and newlines) can be included in properly formatted TSV files, and if so, what the syntax is. (Note: I don't have enough reputation to vote on hold status.)

Comment: No, tabs are not allowed in TSV. "Note that fields that contain tabs are not allowable in this encoding." -https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/tab-separated-values

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file

Answer (score 2):

The abbreviation CSV means "Comma Separated Values", but in practice, this abbreviation is used for all files containing values that are separated by some separator-character. That's why spreadsheet applications like Open Office Calc or Microsoft Excel open up a dialog window letting you configure the separator and quoting character when you attempt to open a file with the file-extension `.csv`.

If your question is how the separator-character can be part of a value of a CSV file, the most common way is quoting the values. Here is in example of the quoting being done with the values

```
a,b
c"d
     e
```

with `,` as the separator character and `"` as the quoting character

```
"a,b","c""d",   e
```

The second way of quoting is the way Excel does it, you can also see variants where the quoting is done in the same way as the first example.

There are libraries out there that do the parsing and creation of CSV files for you. We "here" use the Ostermiller CSV library (there might be better ones nowerday but it does its job so there was no need to change the library after we introduced it "here" 10 years ago.

Comment: @Fifi So your question is how values of a CSV using some separator can contain said separator as part of the value?`

Comment: As you ask me, I realized the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file). My question is more about tsv files and more generally best practice.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I got it for CSV files and I finally edited my question to focus on TSV files. Maybe, you should update or remove your answer to avoid down-voting.

Comment: @Fifi You don't need to worry about votes to my answer ;-) As already mentioned as comment in your question, it's completely irrelevant if you call a file CSV, TSV, SSV. You can see it as hint what the separator is but in general "out there" you always talk about CSV-files independent of the actual separator being used.

Comment: Note that TSV and CSV are distinct formats. CSV format uses an escape syntax to represent field and record delimiters in the data (typically comma and newline). TSV format does not use escapes, and instead disallows field and record delimiters in the data. Typical delimiters are TAB and newline, but alternate delimiter characters can be used.

Comment: @JonDeg, that's really interesting, do you have source ?

Comment: @Fifi See the [wikipedia tab-separated-values article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values). Third paragraph in particular, where it describes this property as the IANA standard. But it's not just a standard body group recommendation. It is observed by many software packages and data file producers. And it makes sense. Many data sets are largely numeric, and don't require TAB characters in the data. Avoiding escapes sequences is a very useful simplification.

Comment: Interesting, it is not mentioned in the french Wikipedia page : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabulation-separated_values. Unfortunately, it will be one more hurdle to overcome... See my example in the updated question.

Comment: The updated question is about TSV, not CSV, so I think this Answer needs to be updated to be relevant.