# Converting csv to excel with divided columns using c#

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I should convert a csv file to an excel file (.xls).
At this moment I used this code:

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fileOriginal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
wb.SaveAs(fileExcel, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
wb.Close();
app.Quit();
```

the problem is that it creates a file with only one column.

[image]

I would instead like to create the file with already divided columns at each semicolon without having to do it by hand after clicking on Data -> Text in columns -> ...

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can look here for your answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

Mention the xlFileFormat and delimiter value

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fileOriginal, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing,";"
            , Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it does the same thing as before.
It puts everything on a single column.