# Remove columns csv files, some of which contain quoted text including commas

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have a csv file with hundreds of columns and 80 rows. I need to remove the first 13 columns from the file.
I have tried using:

> cut -d, -f1-13 --complement input.csv > output.csv

But the issue is one of the first columns contains quoted text including commas and cut can't deal with this format.
Example input:

> HeaderA, HeaderB, HeaderC, HeaderD, HeaderE, HeaderF, HeaderG, HeaderH
>   A, "B, B", C, "D, D, D, D", E, F, G, H
>   A, "B, B", C, "D, D, D, D", E, F, G, H
>   A, "B, B", C, "D, D, D, D", E, F, G, H

Desired output:

> HeaderE, HeaderF, HeaderG, HeaderH
>   E, F, G, H
>   E, F, G, H
>   E, F, G, H

In the example I am working with a smaller number of columns in similar conditions. Ideally the solution should be extendable to any number of columns and rows (13 columns and 80 rows in my case).
I have tried looking for solutions with awk, but often they include printing all columns except those to remove and this isn't a practical solution due to the sheer number of columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: There is no good way to do this in vanilla bash.  Is there any chance of using a language which has csv parsing included, like python?

Comment: @Alex Stiff how do you know that?

Comment: @AlexStiff I think the two answers submitted disprove your claim.

Comment: Look into using [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/)

Comment: The answers fail to cope with doubled `""` as used in some CSV dialects to quote quotes within a quoted field.

Comment: @CJK - one of the submitted answers was done in Python, not bash, and the other does not handle quotes in quoted strings.

Comment: @AlexStiff The OP has stated the conditions he requires a potential solution to be able to operate under.  Quotes in quoted strings is not one of them.  As you can see from my note, this did cross my mind, and I do have a solution for it, but as it is not required, there's little value in muddying the water with overly complex regex that isn't fruitful.  **PS.**  The second answer to which I referred was done in bash, but has since been deleted for some reason.  It was authored by oguzismail.

Comment: @CJK ah sorry - didn't notice you were the author of the bash response.  I have voted it up because it works for this specific example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work given the specific conditions you've set out:

```
grep -oE '(("[^"]+"|[^,]+),?){5}$' input.csv > output.csv
```

where the `5` in `{5}` is replaced with the number of columns you want *remaining*.  Thus, given *`N`* columns, of which the first 13 are to be omitted, this value would be *`N - 13`*.

**Note:** *The regular expression won't match correctly if any of the quoted column data, themselves, contain quotes, e.g. `"some \"data\" in quotes"`, although the pattern can be adjusted to cater for that (but it becomes quite complex).*

Comment: Thank you, I was only able to test your solution today and it worked, even if it is a bit slower than expected to process. I will try testing the python pandas suggestion as well even if I'd prefer not complicating my script too much.

Comment: Unfortunately I have difficulty implementing your solution on larger files, I am unable to open them in an editor to see how many columns are present in total and I can't make awk correctly count them due to the comma in quotes issue. Therefore I am unable to perform the N-13 calculation necessary for your solution. EDIT: I will still mark your answer as correct as it works for smaller files.

Comment: What if you used `head -n 1 input.csv` to extract the first line of the file, i.e. the header row, and count the columns in that one row.  You can use a similar `grep` to above but without the `{5}`, or a simpler version assuming the headers don’t feature quotes.  The whole thing would be done like this: `head -n 1 input.csv | grep -oE '[^,]+' | wc -l`, the result returned being the total number of columns.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the suggested command works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using pandas in python.

To do so you can write a simple function that does the following:

- Load the csv to pandas dataframe
- Remove the columns that you don't need
- Save the everything back to a new csv file or back to the same.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

def remove_columns_from_csv(data_path):
    #loading the file
    data_file = pd.read_csv(data_path)
    data = pd.dateFrame(data_file)

    # Use this list if you want to remove by columns names 
    columns_list = ['first_columns', 'second_column']

    # Use this list if you want to remove by index
    columns_list = [0,1,3] # subselection of columns you want removed
    data = data.drop(columns=columns_list)

    # saving the data back to a csv
    file_name = 'type the file name here'
    data.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')


# Function call    
datapath = 'C:\\Users\\default_user\\Documents\\csv_filename.csv'
remove_columns_from_csv(datapath)
```

Note: index here starts from zero, so if your columns number is 1 in csv it will correspond to 0 in python.

Comment: I am trying to test your answer, does it require the specific column headers fir the list or can I use the column number or position to identify how many columns to cut?

Comment: Looking at the pandas documentation it seems that the specific labels should be used in the list, which is not very practical as I need to loop the command to apply on multiple csv files that have headers with different prefixes. I need a solution that removes columns based on position/order and not specific label name. I am sorry I didn't specify this in the original question.

Comment: Sure you can remove columns based on position(index). You can simply change the list of labels with the list of indices. I will update the solution and see if that is of any use to you.

Comment: Sorry to bother you further, I am trying to implement your solution but am not very familiar with python. Could you explain better how to use your script? I have installed pandas for both python 2 and 3 on my system and have entered the path to the file where indicated, but still am receiving various errors on the terminal.

Comment: In particular, I am now receiving: ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: It could the data path to the file I believe. 
datapath example in code:

datapath = 'C:\\Users\\singroha\\Documents\\csv_filename.csv'