# How can i ignore comma inside a table field while exporting it to csv?

Tags: javascript

i found this code to download my table content into csv format but the problem is my table field has comma(,) within its field but the function splits the field.

these are the functions:

```
 function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
                var csvFile;
                var downloadLink;

                csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});


                downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

                downloadLink.download = filename;

                downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);


                downloadLink.style.display = "none";

                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);


                downloadLink.click();
            }


        function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
            var csv = [];
            var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

                for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
                    row.push(cols[j].innerText);

                csv.push(row.join(","));        
            }

            // Download CSV file
            downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
        }
```

here is the html code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john@gmail.com</td>
        <td>India,up</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stephen Thomas</td>
        <td>stephen@gmail.com</td>
        <td>UK,london</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Natly Oath</td>
        <td>natly@gmail.com</td>
        <td>France</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="exportTableToCSV('members.csv')">Export HTML Table To CSV 
File</button>
```

the location column of john and natly will be split.

Comment: Do you mean it will split for John and Stephen? Also have you tried to alter the code yourself? It would help us if you showed an attempt as we can guide you through that.

Comment: This would be a good read for you too- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file

Comment: @AndrewLohr hey, i meant it for India and up similarly UK and london

Answer (score 5):

you can use quotes to ignore comma

```
 function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
            var csv = [];
            var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

                for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) 
                    row.push("\""+cols[j].innerText+"\"");

                csv.push(row.join(","));        
            }

            // Download CSV file
            downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
        }
```

Comment: If solution is works then please mark as correct then future user easily find out correct answer