# How can I escape a pipe character in a pipe delimited CSV file?

Tags: csv, pipe, delimiter

I am generating a pipe `|` delimited CSV file whereby one of the columns contains commands which are executed by a given user in powershell.

`User | Date | Command`

However, commands are likely appear as below as the pipe character leads one command to another:

`command one | command two | command three`

How can I treat each command in my python code so that the pipe characters within commands do not affect the delimiting of the CSV file?

I have considered replacing the pipe character with an alternate character however this would ruin the context of the command.

Comment: It depends on the flavour of CSV that you're using — what does the consuming process expect?  One common option is to enclose the fields containing the delimiter inside double quotes, doubling up any double quotes that appear inside the field:   `"User | Date | Command"` for your example.  Another option is to escape the delimiter, typically with a backslash: `User \| Date \| Command`.  There may be other alternatives, but those are the most common ones.

Comment: Thanks, escaping seems to have resolved the problem: `string.replace('|','\|')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)