# exporting to csv text containig the delimiter character

Tags: php, csv, export

I am exporting some text to csv using php.
The problem is that the text sometimes contains the csv delimiter.
The user decide what the delimiter will be so i can't change it.
How do i make the text go into one cell and not split into different cells?

thank you all

Comment: Use `fputcsv` and provide your delimiter

Answer (score 1):

Use double-quotes, like so:

```
foo,"bar,baz"
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/769675/1012576.