# split csv, one of the tabs is an array

Tags: c#, csv, parsing

I have a .csv file which goes like this

```
"a1,b1,c1,d1", foo1, goo1 
"a2,b2,c2,d2", foo2, goo2
```

and I would like to parse it to an object of

```
string[] letters
string foo
string goo
```

so the data is

```
letters = [a1,b1,c1,d1]
foo = "foo1"
goo = "goo1"
--------------------
letters = [a2,b2,c2,d2]
foo = "foo2"
goo = "goo2"
```

now

```
line.Split(',');
```

won't work, how can I fix that?

c#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file 

This may help you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say:

> now line.Split(','); won't work

At first this does not make any sense, because you have not shown us any code using `line.Split()`, nor is there, under normal circumstances, any need to use `line.Split()` when dealing with CSV files.

So, what this is telling us is that instead of using a CSV library to read your CSV file, you are trying to parse the file yourself, with custom, hand-written code.  And of course you are doing this in the most naive way possible, that is, with `line.Split()`.

Don't do that.

Do yourself a favor and get the 'CSVHelper' library from NuGet and let it do your CSV parsing for you.  That's the "normal circumstances" that I was talking about, and that's why normally `line.Split()` is not needed.

Then, once you have read your array field into a string, you can go ahead and use `field.Split()` on it.

The CSVHelper library is a bit of an overkill, as it does a lot more than what you actually need.  For example, it can read lines from a CSV file directly into the members of a class representing a row of your CSV file.  But it is okay: for several decades now, the entire software industry has been in the habit of using existing libraries for any trivial task at hand, even if only a tiny subset is needed from the entire wealth of functionality offered by the library.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get `"a1,b1,c1,d1", foo1,goo1` into the same list, you can try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass 
{
  public static void Main (string[] args) 
  {
    List<String> items = new List<String>();
    string[] stuff = {"a1","b1","c1","d1", "foo1", "goo1"};
    items.AddRange(stuff);
    items.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));
    List<String> letters = new List<String>();
    List<String> foo = new List<String>();
    List<String> goo = new List<String>();
    foreach(string a in items)
    {
      if(a.Contains("foo"))
      {
        foo.Add(a);
      }
      else if(a.Contains("goo"))
      {
        goo.Add(a);
      }
      else
      {
        letters.Add(a);
      }
    }
    letters.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));
    foo.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));
    goo.ForEach(i => Console.Write("{0}\t", i));
  }
}
```