# Read a csv that has double quotes with comma inside

Tags: java, csv

UPDATE: WORKING SOLUTION POSTED BELOW

I'm trying to process a csv file and I'm splitting it by comma. However, there are couple places with quotes that has comma embedded.

Example: "# 29. Toxic substances properly identified, stored, used"

Every quote that has a comma in there is wrapped around with " ", is there a way to detect this double quotes and work around the commas?

Thanks!

Original code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class csvFileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csvFile = "/Users/zzmle/Desktop/data.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        int count=0;       

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            String firstline = br.readLine();
            String[] header = firstline.split(",");
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && count<10) {
                //comma is the separator
                String[] Restaurant = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                for (int i=0; i<header.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(header[i]+": "+Restaurant[i]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println("-------------------");
                count++;
            }

        }   catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Working Solution:

```
// @author Zhiming Zhao
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class csvFileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String csvFile = "data.csv"; 
        BufferedReader br = null; 
        String line = ""; 
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        int count=0;       

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            String firstline = br.readLine();
            String[] header = firstline.split(cvsSplitBy);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && count<10) { //count<10 is for testing purposes                
                String[] Restaurant = line.split(cvsSplitBy); //comma is the separator
                process(Restaurant); //this is to deal with the commas within quotation marks (which split the elements and shifts them into the wrong places)

                //this part prints the header + restaurant for the first ten lines
                for (int i=0; i<header.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(header[i]+": "+Restaurant[i]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println("-------------------");
                count++;
            }

        }   catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("The file cannot be found, check if the file is under root directory");
        }   catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Input & Output operations error");
        }   finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // @brief This function specifically deal with the issue of commas within the quotation marks
    // @detail it gets the index number of the 2 elements containing the quotation marks, then concats them all. It works with multiple quotation marks on the same line
    public static void process(String[] data) {
        int index1 = -1; //initialize the index of the first ", -1 for empty
        int index2 = 0;  //initialize the index of the second ", 0 for empty
        for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            if (String.valueOf(data[i].charAt(0)).equals("\"") && index1 == -1) { //if index1 is not empty and the first char of current element is "
                index1 = i; //set index1 to current index number
            }
            if (String.valueOf(data[i].charAt(data[i].length()-1)).equals("\"") && index1 != -1) { //if index1 is not empty and the last char of current element is "
                index2 = i; //set index2 to current index number
                multiconcat(index1, index2, data); //concat the elements between index1 and index2 
                data = multidelet(index1+1, index2, data); //delete the elements that were copied (index1+1:index2)
                i -= (index2-index1); //this is to reset the cursor back to index1 (could be replaced with i = index1)
                index1 = -1; //set index1 to empty

            }
        }    
    }

    // @brief Copy all elements between index1 and index2 to index1, doesn't return anything
    public static void multiconcat(int index1, int index2, String[] data) {
        for (int i=index1+1; i<=index2; i++) {
            data[index1] += data[i];
        }
    }

    // @brief Deletes the elements between index1+1 and index2 
    public static String[] multidelet(int index1, int index2, String[] data) {
        String[] newarr = new String[data.length-(index2-index1+1)];
        int n = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            if (index1 <= i && i <= index2) continue;
            newarr[n] = data[i];
            n++;
        }
        return newarr;

    }
}
```

[The csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CnXx.png)

Output (one of the lines with quotation mark and comma embedded), although it's not perfect (the comma within quotation mark got eaten), it's a minor issue and I'm too lazy to fix it lol :

````
serial_number: DA08R0TCU 
activity_date: 03/30/2018 12:00:00 AM 
facility_name: KRUANG TEDD 
violation_code: F035 
violation_description: "# 35. Equipment/Utensils - approved; installed; clean; good repair capacity" 
violation_status:  capacity" 
points: OUT OF COMPLIANCE 
grade: 1 
facility_address: A 
facility_city: 5151 HOLLYWOOD BLVD 
facility_id: LOS ANGELES 
facility_state: FA0064949 
facility_zip: CA 
employee_id: 90027 
owner_id: EE0000857 
owner_name: OW0001034 
pe_description: 5151 HOLLYWOOD LLC 
program_element_pe: RESTAURANT (31-60) SEATS HIGH RISK 
program_name: 1635 
program_status: KRUANG TEDD 
record_id: ACTIVE 
score: PR0031205 
service_code: 92 
service_description: 1 
row_id: ROUTINE INSPECTION ```
````

Comment: Use a proper CSV library instead of `firstline.split(",");` - good luck!

Comment: thanks, i'll try that

Comment: Ignore commas when you are inside quotes. Easy! Process string character by character..

Comment: @JGFMK How do I do that? That's exactly what I need! Can you post some sort of solution to that?
Also, my csv file has 100k lines, will it slow down the runtime if I process it char by char?

Comment: I would imagine so. yes,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23412989/495157 This has been asked before....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own solution:
Read the first character of each element, if the first character is a double quote, concat this and the next ones (will need to use recursion for this) until there's an element with a double quote as the last character.

This will run considerably faster than reading char by char, as suggested by JGFMK.
And I am not allowed to use external libraries for this project.

STILL IMPLEMENTING THIS, I will update if it works

EDIT: Working solution posted in original post

Answer (score 2):

don't reinvent the wheel: there are libs to read csv around e.g. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/
http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/
https://code.google.com/archive/p/jcsv/

Comment: My project specification doesn't allow me to use external libraries