# Change the value of specific cell in CSV using bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk, syntax

I want to change the value of specific cell in CSV using the bash command line.

I have a sellers.csv:

```
seller_id,seller_zip_code_prefix,seller_city,seller_state
3442f8959a84dea7ee197c632cb2df15,13023,campinas,SP
723a46b89fd5c3ed78ccdf039e33ac63,93310,novo hamburgo, rio grande do sul, brasil,RS
```

As you can see, row 3 column 3 (seller_city) is violating the rule because it contains commas. That's why MySQL is saying "Row 3 contained more data than there were input columns".
I want to change `novo hamburgo, rio grande do sul, brasil` into `novo hamburgo rio grande do sul brasil`.
I tried `awk` but its saying I am supplying wrong arguments.

```
awk -v r=553 -v c=3 -v val="novo hamburgo - rio grande do sul - brasil" -F sellers.csv
```

**awk: option requires an argument -- F**

Comment: What is the `-F` option for? What does the documentation say?

Comment: -F is field separator assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to replace the commas, just quote your fields:

```
$ awk -F',' -v OFS='","' '{city=$0; sub(/([^,]*,){2}/,"",city); sub(/,[^,]*$/,"",city); print "\"" $1, $2, city, $NF "\""}' sellers.csv
"seller_id","seller_zip_code_prefix","seller_city","seller_state"
"3442f8959a84dea7ee197c632cb2df15","13023","campinas","SP"
"723a46b89fd5c3ed78ccdf039e33ac63","93310","novo hamburgo, rio grande do sul, brasil","RS"
```

But if you really don't want to do that you could do:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {city=$0; sub(/([^,]*,){2}/,"",city); sub(/,[^,]*$/,"",city); gsub(/ *, */," - ",city); print $1, $2, city, $NF}' sellers.csv
seller_id,seller_zip_code_prefix,seller_city,seller_state
3442f8959a84dea7ee197c632cb2df15,13023,campinas,SP
723a46b89fd5c3ed78ccdf039e33ac63,93310,novo hamburgo - rio grande do sul - brasil,RS
```

For anything else, see [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
Initially, I removed the quotes. The standard CSV place strings in " quotes in order to avoid internal ',' . That's why MySQL was reading some integer values in CSV as string. To solve this problem, I had to remove quotes from CSV. I did this using bash command:

    awk '{gsub(/\"/,"")};1' input.csv 

But it caused to another error. In row 553, there is a value for seller_city as `novo hamburgo, rio grande do sul, brasil`. That's why MySQL gave Error: "Row 553 contained more data than there were input columns". Now I should fix this problem. I'll try your advice

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to produce the csv file with `|` instead of `,` .
This solution you avoid this problem.

The standard `csv` place strings in `"` quotes in order to avoid internal `,`  .

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file).

Comment: you are absolutely right: CSV place strings in " quotes. That's why MySQL was reading some integer values in CSV as a string. To solve this problem, I had to remove quotes from CSV. I did this using bash command:

    awk '{gsub(/\"/,"")};1' input.csv 

But it caused to another error. In row 553, there is a value for seller_city as `novo hamburgo, rio grande do sul, brasil`. That's why MySQL gave Error: "Row 553 contained more data than there were input columns". To fix this problem, I had to search for the solution of replacing commas with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;s/,/&/4;T;s// -/3;ta' file
```

If the current line has four `,`'s replace the third by  `-` and repeat until failure.